tf.function converts variable to tensor automatically
It seems that a tf.function is not able to return a tf.variable. For example, the code below fails on the second call to run_episode.
@tf.function
def run_episode(x,actions) : 

    actions = actions.scatter_nd_update([[x]],[[action]])

    return actions

actions = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((max_mem_size,1),dtype=tf.int32))

actions = run_episode(1,actions)
actions = run_episode(2,actions)

I need to keep the memory of all the moves taken in a game. I've tried TensorArray and now Variable, but tensorflow seems unable to manage a memory variable within a graph function.
Anyone know how I can make run_episode return a tf.Variable?

Hi, what tf version are you using? Code works fine for me. I have tensorflow==2.16.1

How about adding return tf.Variable(actions, trainable=False) inside run_episode body?

@JohnnyCheesecutter, sorry. My first line of code was cut off. That line is @tf.function.  You're right that the code works if it's not a graph function. But returning actions as a variable does not fix the problem.

how about using stack and unstack?
max_mem_size = 5
action = 3

@tf.function
def run_episode(x,actions) : 
    a_list = tf.unstack(actions)
    a_list[x] = action
    actions = tf.stack(a_list)
    return actions


actions = tf.cast(tf.zeros(max_mem_size,1), tf.int32)
actions = run_episode(1, actions)
actions = run_episode(2, actions)

